# Post count for category and tag

Tags: categories, query-posts

I have this code that counts the result found when a search is made. Here goes the code.

```
<?php /* Search Count */ 
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    $text  = '<span class="resultsFound">';
if ( $allsearch->found_posts <= 0 ) {
    $text .= sprintf(__( '( Nothing Found )' ), $count );
}

elseif ( $allsearch->found_posts <= 1 ) {
    $text .= sprintf(__( '( We found %d company )' ), $count );
} 

else {
    $text .= sprintf(__( '( We found %d companies )' ), $count );
}       
$text .= '</span>'; 
echo $text;
?>
```

The code above is the code for counting all the post found in search page. I want to apply this function to my category as well as tag page. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run a custom query to get the post count. This is already done by the main query. What you are doing is the same as eating the same piece of meat twice. :-)

As said, the main query already return the amount of posts found via the `$found_posts` property. You can access and display it anywhere on a page as follows

```
echo $wp_query->found_posts;
```

This will print the amount of posts that the main query found that mathes the URL request.

You can use the following on any page in your site, just change the text as needed

```
<?php 
    /* Search Count */ 
    $count = $wp_query->found_posts; 
    $text  = '<span class="resultsFound">';
if ( $count  <= 0 ) {
    $text .= sprintf(__( '( Nothing Found )' ), $count );
}

elseif ( $count <= 1 ) {
    $text .= sprintf(__( '( We found %d company )' ), $count );
} 

else {
    $text .= sprintf(__( '( We found %d companies )' ), $count );
}       
$text .= '</span>'; 
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I tried your code. But, that is only showing number instead of "1 result found" or "2 results found". Would you please implement a code which works that way? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please see my update. I have taken your code from your question and modified it. It will work anywhere. You can replace your code with mine. Just change the wording on your pages

Comment: Thanks Peter! But, would it work on tag page as well?

Comment: Yes, you can drop it in any page like your tag pages and category pages

Comment: Just one note, in my code, please remove the `$key` part. Will update code now

Comment: Well Peter, thanks so much for your answer! The code works very well. The code in my question was actually provided by you in earlier too. :)

Comment: Hahaha, great. Enjoy :-)